# SQL SERVER Management Studio Has been expired

Tags: sql-server

I am facing this issue from last 2 months. Evaluation period has been expired of management studio 2008 sql server.

I purchase licence version but not able to upgrade it.

Can you please suggest how can i do upgrade because they dont give me the product key.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the SQL Server itself, not the management studio tool, has the licence problem.

You should go back to the vendor and talk to them; they sold you a licence so there is a product key which you need. Sometimes the product key is embedded in the DVD / ISO image, so you need to run the installer from the new media.

Answer (score 1):

Sql Server Management does not expire. Maybe you got a trial edition of a complete Sql Server edition.

If not, the seller must supply it.